# I can't get the button to center over the image when hovered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

when the image is hovered on, a button appears; the button is towards the left and I need to get it centered in the middle. I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and bootsrap v3.3.4. Everything works properly except for the button not centering. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
<figcaption>
<h4>
<a href="#">
                                    Test       
</a>
</h4>
<p>
                                test
</p>
</figcaption>
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="image1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="title" >
<div class="overlay">
<div class="buttons">       
<a target="_blank" href="">Discover</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<figcaption>
<h4>
<a href="#">
                                    test       
</a>
</h4>
<p>
                                test
</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
figure {
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 45px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

figure .img-wrapper {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

figure img {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 400ms;
transition: transform 400ms;
}

figure:hover img {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
}

figure:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

figure:hover .overlay .buttons a {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

figure .overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms;
transition: opacity 400ms;
}

figure .overlay a {
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 23px;
line-height: 1;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 0px;
margin: 4px;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition: all 400ms;
transition: all 400ms;
}

figure .overlay a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

figure .overlay:hover a {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

figure .buttons {
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 24%;
}

figure figcaption {
padding: 20px 25px;
margin-top: 0;
color: #666;
}

figure figcaption h4 {
margin: 0;
}

figure figcaption h4 a {
color: #02bdd5;
}

figure figcaption p {
font-size: 16px;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll use `flexbox`, this will be easier to achieve (even with bootstrap's responsive design), and will be supported by [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

In order to do that, change your css as follows:

```
figure .buttons {
  /* remove all styles */
}

figure .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms;
  transition: opacity 400ms;

  /* Added styles: */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

(This will also work if you add more buttons to your `.buttons` element)

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/qZZgmw) with a working demo

Comment: The button is still shifted to the left

Comment: For me it's centered. On what browser and OS are you on?

Comment: I think I figured it out figure:hover .overlay .buttons a {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: auto;